# Java : the method to instantiate an object

Tags: java

While I'm reading the spring tutorial, I found something like this:

```
LocalChangeInterceptor localChangeInterceptor;
localChangeInterceptor = new LocalChangeInterceptor();
```

So what is the difference with this manner?

```
LocalChangeInterceptor localChangeInterceptor = new LocalChangeInterceptor();
```

Also, I want to know why people prefer

```
if (String.class.equals(sourceType.getType()))
```

to

```
if (sourceType.getType().equals(String.class))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `LocalChangeInterceptor localChangeInterceptor = new LocalChangeInterceptor();`

   is *effectively* the same as

   ```
   LocalChangeInterceptor localChangeInterceptor;
   localChangeInterceptor = new LocalChangeInterceptor();
   ```

   But, you sometimes have to split the assignment to extend the **scope** of a *reference*. For example, while opening a database `Connection` you would split the declaration so that the `connection` reference is available in the `finally` block.

   ```
   Connection connection;
   try {
       connection = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
       // Do statement stuff that may throw exceptions
   } catch (SQLException e) {
      // Handle exception
   } finally {
     // Close connection
     if (connection != null) { // Available inside finally,
         connection.close(); // because declared outside the try block
     }
   }
   ```
2. With

   ```
   if (String.class.equals(sourceType.getType()))
   ```

   you avoid a `NullPointerExcpetion` if `getType()` returns `null`.

   That's because when the you flip the code to

   ```
   if (sourceType.getType().equals(String.class)) {
   ```

   at *runtime* it tries to execute

   ```
   if (**null**.equals(String.class)) { // NPE!
   ```

Comment: Maybe explain how it avoid the NullPointerException - because String.class always exists and equals() can be used on null.

Answer (score 2):

In this:

```
LocalChangeInterceptor localChangeInterceptor;
localChangeInterceptor = new LocalChangeInterceptor();
```

what you do is you first create a reference to a `LocalChangeInterceptor` and then create a new object in the second line and pass its reference to your variable.

In the second one you do the same but in one step. You create the reference and immediately pass a value to it.

```
LocalChangeInterceptor localChangeInterceptor = new LocalChangeInterceptor();
```

This: `if (String.class.equals(sourceType.getType()))` is the same with:
`if (sourceType.getType().equals(String.class))`

Also I want to give you one tip. Stackoverflow is not the right place to teach yourself programming. This question for example. You could have answer it on your own if you searched a little more. I **strongly recommend** that you put some more effort into this. Teaching yourself programming is not an easy task.

Good luck though.

Comment: I selected the answer I need and I am sure you would understand better what I wanne to know from this question. although, thank you for your answer. Sometimes I just want to know why, instead of how.

Answer (score 1):

The previous anwswer from @TheCrafter answers part one of your question.

However, why people prefer

```
if (String.class.equals(sourceType.getType()))
```

to

```
if (sourceType.getType().equals(String.class))
```

if because the second variant can throw NullPointerException.

It is better to call the `equals` method on a known constant value that can never be `null`. `String.class` fulfills that.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, the only difference is that **the variable is initialized after it's declared**.  This is useful in some cases, where a variable won't be used for a while, thus not needing to contain any data until used. Look into lazy initialization.

For the second one, the idea is **to prevent `NullPointerException`**. If `sourceType.getType()` returned `null`, your second example would throw a NPE, *since we are trying to call `equals` from a variable which references null*. But in the first example, we are calling `equals` off something we KNOW won't be null. If `sourceType.getType()` was null in the first example, `equals` would simply return false instead of a NPE being thrown. Passing `null` into the equals method will return false

Answer (score 0):

Because `sourceType.getType()` might return null and `String.class` always return `class java.lang.String`.

So ? Whats wrong with null ?

Well, if you translate it after the result returned the null value, you can read the following code 

`if (sourceType.getType().equals(String.class))`

become like this

`if (null.equals(String.class))`

and your code will ended have `NullPointerException` error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no functional difference between these two statements.

```
LocalChangeInterceptor localChangeInterceptor = new LocalChangeInterceptor();

LocalChangeInterceptor localChangeInterceptor;
localChangeInterceptor = new LocalChangeInterceptor();
```

Choosing between them is primarily stylistic, and usually only makes a difference if you are trying to prevent overly long lines.

---

There is a subtle, but important, difference between the different equality checks.

```
String.class.equals(sourceType.getType())`

`sourceType.getType().equals(String.class)`
```

Behave very differently in one important case, but (as TheCrafter mentioned) you should be able to figure out on your own with a little bit of effort.

If you get stuck, consider the possible values of `sourceType`, and how that could affect the behavior of the two versions of that statement.